# unable to scroll the screen which has grid view and listview below it

Tags: java, android, listview, scrollview

I have the following xml which has Gridview and framelayout below it.
My requirement is if I scroll the screen upwards whole screen should scroll, but for me Only listview scrolls

Below is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/time_card_header"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">
<GridView
     android:id="@+id/timecard_grid"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="130dp"
     android:layout_margin="3dp"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
     android:numColumns="3"
     android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
     android:verticalSpacing="1dp" />
    </ScrollView>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/timecard_reports"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"/>
</RelativeLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually GridView and Listview have already scroll. No need to put the above widgets in scrollview. Firstly, remove the scrollview. I think you need the FrameLayout to be fixed at the bottom and show gridview above. For that first use FrameLayout in the linear layout with align_parentbottom true. after that please place the gridview above FrameLayout. That will fix the problem.

Comment: so if i scroll the screen, does grid view and framelayout scroll simultaneously?

Comment: i dont want framelayout to scroll separately. when i scroll upwards all the screen should scroll along with gridview to the last item of listview

Comment: Please have a look at http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/03/combining-gridview-and-listview-in-one.html. This will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Just put linearlayout below scroll view and then gridview.

```
<scrollview>
<linearlayout >
<gridview />
</linearlayout >
</scrollview>
```

Sorry i am giving the ans from the mobile but the concept is same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager and set nestedScrollingEnabled of recyclerView to false.
and instead of ScrollView use NestedScrollView as parent of RecyclerView:

```
   private void setUpRecyclerView(View view) {
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(id.repliesList);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),numberOfColumns));
}
```

and xml file:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/nestedScroll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <RecyclerView
             android:id="@+id/timecard_grid"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="130dp"
             android:layout_margin="3dp"
             android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
             android:gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
             android:numColumns="3"
             android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
             android:verticalSpacing="1dp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/timecard_reports"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"/>
        </RelativeLayout
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```